# Xcode 3.2.2 and localization of Settings.bundle

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode3.2, settings.bundle

I have just discovered that after upgrading to the latest Xcode 3.2.2, I am not able anymore to localize Settings.bundle. The "Make File Localizable button always appears grayed out, and the Settings.bundle files appear with "No Explicit File Encoding", instead of UTF-16.

This happens not just for my old projects, it happens even for new projects.
Any clue? Is the localization procedure changed?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks very strange, maybe need to report to [bugreport](http://bugreport.apple.com)? But here is workaround that works.

1. Reveal your `Settings.bundle` in Finder.
2. Right click (or Ctrl-click) on it and select *Show Package contents*.
3. Copy `en.lproj` and rename to desired language (e.g., `fr.lproj`).

Now you can go back to Xcode and edit localized `Root.strings` and files as you need.